# Json Decoding Failed?

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=1&limit=50 
I am using this Json file but when I try to decode it shows null.

I have tried

'''

```
List imgData;

final String url = 'https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=1&limit=50';
Future getData() async {
var response = await http
    .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'});

List data = jsonDecode(response.body)['results'];
setState(() {
  imgData = data;
});
}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
this.getData();
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSON to dart tool](https://app.quicktype.io/), which is available online for free.

Paste your JSON to left panel and select dart language from upper right corner,

You will get your dart class code, in which you can use methods like .toMap() and .toJson(),

And it is very fast with less human error.

This can be very helpful for huge JSON data.

You will get class like this for your Data, from this tool.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final data = dataFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<Data> dataFromJson(String str) => List<Data>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Data.fromMap(x)));

String dataToJson(List<Data> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toMap())));

class Data {
    String id;
    String author;
    int width;
    int height;
    String url;
    String downloadUrl;

    Data({
        this.id,
        this.author,
        this.width,
        this.height,
        this.url,
        this.downloadUrl,
    });

    factory Data.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        id: json["id"],
        author: json["author"],
        width: json["width"],
        height: json["height"],
        url: json["url"],
        downloadUrl: json["download_url"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "author": author,
        "width": width,
        "height": height,
        "url": url,
        "download_url": downloadUrl,
    };
}
```

Thereafter you can use dataFromJson method.

this can be full implementation for your code.

```
import 'dart:convert';

List imgData;

final String url = 'https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=1&limit=50';
Future getData() async {
  var response = await http
      .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'});

  List data = dataFromJson(response.body);
  setState(() {
    imgData = data;
  });
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  this.getData();
}


List<Data> dataFromJson(String str) => List<Data>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Data.fromMap(x)));

String dataToJson(List<Data> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toMap())));

class Data {
  String id;
  String author;
  int width;
  int height;
  String url;
  String downloadUrl;

  Data({
    this.id,
    this.author,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.url,
    this.downloadUrl,
  });

  factory Data.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
    id: json["id"],
    author: json["author"],
    width: json["width"],
    height: json["height"],
    url: json["url"],
    downloadUrl: json["download_url"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "id": id,
    "author": author,
    "width": width,
    "height": height,
    "url": url,
    "download_url": downloadUrl,
  };
}
```

Comment: Hello, Can you Just help me where you said 'you can use methods like .toMap() and .toJson(),' any guide? beginner finding my way out through this

Comment: Yes i have edited the answer. if you have any further issues feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace below

```
List data = jsonDecode(response.body)['results'];
```

with

```
List data = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

there is no **results** param in your JSON